# How to speed up my mysql query with group by?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Hi all I have this table schema

```
create table user_activities
(
    id                   int unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    user_id              int unsigned                        not null,
    other_user_id        int unsigned                        not null,
    activity_type_id tinyint unsigned                    not null,
    reason               varchar(255)                        null,
    created_at           timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    updated_at           timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    constraint user_activities_user_id_other_user_id_unique
        unique (user_id, other_user_id),
    constraint user_activities_other_user_id_foreign
        foreign key (other_user_id) references users (id),
    constraint user_activities_activity_type_id_foreign
        foreign key (activity_type_id) references user_activity_types (id),
    constraint user_activities_user_id_foreign
        foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
)
    engine = InnoDB
    collate = utf8_unicode_ci;

create index user_activities_other_user_id_index
    on user_activities (other_user_id);

create index user_activities_activity_type_id_index
    on user_activities (activity_type_id);

create index user_activities_user_id_index
    on user_activities (user_id);
```

The table has now `6515846` rows

**Goal**

I want to write a query to get the users that had the most recent activity in the last 7 days.
I need rows of user_id, mostrecentuseractivitydate

Then in the code I will do some action on them.

My query at the moment is

```
select updated_at, user_id from  user_activities
where created_at > '2022-08-08 15:16:55'
group by user_id
order by max(updated_at) desc
limit 10;
```

The `explain` statement result is

```
1,SIMPLE,user_activities,,index,"user_activities_user_id_other_user_id_unique,user_activities_user_id_index",user_activities_user_id_index,4,,6416255,33.33,Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

**Problem**

**The query above with the given schema and number of rows takes forever like 5 minutes... and sometimes I receive no response and query hangs forever**

That is not acceptable for my requirement.

Any ideas how to speed that up ?

I have already foreign_key as you can see from table schema on the `user_id` field and the innodb I think also generates index automatically on the foreign key.

I am also adding the where created_at >  clause to reduce only the the items in the 7 days.
**I even tried without adding the where created_at and did not change much to be honest.**
Anyway I am interested only in the data from last 7 days so that where clause can stay

Comment: This makes no sense at all: `order by max(updated_at) desc`. What is the max function supposed to do here?

Comment: @nl-x, That's valid SQL in a grouping query. The result has one row per group, and each group does have a `max(updated_at)`. The order by sorts the resulting rows by that expression. The expression does not strictly have to be in the select-list of the query.

Comment: updated_at will be set on an insert to I would test updated_at rather than created at , I would also SELECT ID,MAX(UPDATED_AT) FROM T where updated_at > '2022-08-08 15:16:55' group by id; then think about adding a key on updated_at.

Comment: @Kristi Jorgji - You don't know who downvoted so nipping at ni-x is out of order. The question may have been downvoted because you did not include an explain plan which should always be included in performance questions also you did not include sample data and expected outcome to clarify your requirement. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks that is useful to know and more constructive. I will try to update my question with explain result as well. Done - updated with explain as well

Answer (score 1):

You need an index on `created_at`. Others might be useful as well, but start there.

Comment: I can create one index there as well but I don't think that is the main problem. Even when I remove `where created_at >=` part so without any where it is still slow as hell. Even when adding LIMIT 10 in the end still super slow

Comment: Did you try it? The `WHERE` clause with an index should speed things up because you're limiting the number of rows to consider, and won't have to walk the entire table to find the relevant rows.  You may also want to take a look at https://use-the-index-luke.com to learn about how best to use indexes. Finally, when someone makes a suggestion when you've asked for help, it's sensible to try the suggestion before declaring "I don't think that is the main problem". If you knew what the main problem was, you wouldn't be asking.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a composite key with user_id and created_at in it.

This key should make it possible to do the group by as well as the where clause at the same time.

Try this:

```
create index user_activities_user_id_created_at on user_activities (user_id, created_at);
```

Comment: I am having the problem also when I don't write the `where` clause and let it without created_at >=. Is this creating index on the user_id ```  constraint user_activities_user_id_foreign
        foreign key (user_id) references users (id)``` it should in innodb

Comment: Why do you use both `created_at` and `updated_at` ? Could you use `updated_at` in the where as well?